# dynamic allocation for variable in struct

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to figure out where my problem is and can't seem to find it,
I want to a allocate dynamic memory to a variable within a struct,
I have tried in all sorts of ways and it just does not work
I get a warning: **Exception has occurred. segmentation fault**

When I allocate memory to the **bookcase*  its works but when i try to allocate to a variable within the structure i get the warning.

example of what I was trying to do

```
struct book
 {
  int num;
  char* book_name;
 }*bookcase;

void addbook(void)
 {
  char buff[20];
  gets(buff);
  bookcase->book_name = ( char *)malloc(strlen(buff));
  strcpy(bookcase->book_name,buff);
 }
```

Sorry for the question feels really stupid, unfortunately i could not understand the problem,
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't even move to dynamic allocation until you understand [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102) In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Post the input used for `gets(buff);`

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating enough memory.

A string in C is terminated by a null byte.  The amount of space you're allocating doesn't account for that null byte, so you write past the end of allocated memory when you copy the string.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes a crash.

Add space for the null byte when allocating:

```
bookcase->book_name = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
strcpy(bookcase->book_name,buff);
```

Or, if your system supports it, use `strdup` which does the allocation and copy in one step:

```
bookcase->book_name = strdup(buff);
```

Comment: May want to address the fact that `bookcase` is just an uninitialized pointer to type `struct book` so `bookcase->book_name` is Undefined Behavior (even before you get to the too short allocation).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The code that calls `addbook` isn't shown, and the question mentions allocating memory for `bookcase`, so there's an assumption that that was done correctly.

Comment: Good point. But based on what's shown that jumped out.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to allocate memory for the struct itself

```
bookcase = malloc(sizeof(*bookcase));
```

then you need to allocate enough memory for the title. You do not allocate enough as string in C is terminated by the bull character and this nill char is not counted by the `strlen`

```
bookcase -> book_name = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
```

But you do not two allocations for that.

```
struct book
 {
  int num;
  char book_name[];
 };

struct book *addbook(void)
 {
  char buff[20];
  struct book *bookcase;
  fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin); 
  /* you should check for errors in all I/O operations and memory allocations */
  bookcase = malloc(sizeof(*bookcase) + strlen(buff) + 1);
  strcpy(bookcase->book_name,buff);
  return bookcase;
 }
```